# How to detect users setting do-not-track

Tags: php, do-not-track

I was looking through some Google articles and some Firefox developer areas and found that there was an [option you can set](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-turn-do-not-track-feature) to not let some sites track your information.

I looked into this and did some google searches for Developers and couldn't manage to find any information on how to detect whether or not a user has set this in their browser.

Is it sent in a `POST` request or in any type of request? Does it come in the User agent? I just wanted to know how to manage this and not store their `ips` for login as an example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's sent as [an HTTP header](http://donottrack.us/):

```
function dnt_enabled()
{
   return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DNT']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_DNT'] == 1);
}

if dnt_enabled() {
    // do stuff...
}
```

Or, if you're using PHP 7:

```
function dnt_enabled(): bool
{
   return (bool)$_SERVER['HTTP_DNT'] ?? false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Navigator.doNotTrack

If you want to use client-side JavaScript to check whether or not a user has the [`dnt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/DNT) request header set, you can use [`navigator.doNotTrack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/doNotTrack).

This property returns the value of the [`dnt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/DNT) HTTP header (i.e., `"1"`, `"0"`, or `"unspecified"`).

**You can access this value via PHP by POSTing this value via AJAX.**

```js
const is_not_trackable = navigator.doNotTrack === '1';

console.log(is_not_trackable); // True if user has requested privacy via DNT
console.log(navigator.doNotTrack); // Current value of DNT header
```

> **Note:** At the time of posting, `navigator.doNotTrack` is still considered experimental technology. Expect behavior to change in the future, and proceed with caution before using it in your application. See [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/doNotTrack#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

```
$do_not_track_requested = ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_DNT' ] );
```

All HTTP headers are present in `$_SERVER`, prefixed with `HTTP_`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#89567